# What is the 'jQuery' for Html 5?

Tags: javascript, html, wrapper

At least for me, jQuery changed javascript in an incredible way, at least for what DOM manipulation/ajax concerns.

Now I am starting to get into HTML 5 and I wonder if there is any library that can do what jQuery did to dom, but for html apis, such as DB storage/ retrieval, gps/location, etc. Some sort of wrapper to simplify the development using this technologies.

thanks!

Comment: While it's far more than this now, frameworks like jQuery began primarily to eliminate the inconsistencies and shortcomings of the DOM and javascript implementations across browsers. The core selection engine is just javascript's `querySelectorAll` -- except not all browsers still in common use support it. HTML5 had the benefit of a long design process, and shouldn't suffer the same legacy problems (at least at first).

Answer (score 6):

Probably jQuery will be the jQuery for HTML 5. It already has a rich plugin ecosystem, so some html5-y things will probably make it into core jQuery and the rest will be taken care of as 3rd party plugins. Doing a little googling it looks like there are already quite a few html5-centric plugins available.

Answer (score 1):

Modernizr is making a lot of noise about making HTML5 and CSS3 development easier ... though I haven't had chance to check the internals yet [Modinizr Home Page](http://www.modernizr.com/)